# How can I find two elements in an array that sum to k

Tags: java, arrays

Suppose you are given an array of unsorted integers as

```
A = {3,4,5,1,4,2}
```

Input : `6` 
Output : `{5,1}, {4,2}`

How can I do this in O(n) or O(log n). Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**Update:**
Can we write something more efficient than this?

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length-1;i++)  
{  
    if(array[i]+array[i+1]==6)  
        System.out.println("{"+array[i]+","+array[i+1]+"}");  
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Given two arrays a and b .Find all pairs of elements (a1,b1) such that a1 belongs to Array A and b1 belongs to Array B whose sum a1+b1 = k ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815116/given-two-arrays-a-and-b-find-all-pairs-of-elements-a1-b1-such-that-a1-belong)

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630363/find-two-elements-in-an-array-that-sum-to-k

Comment: In your example you assume the two integers are adjacent. Is this deliberate? for `k=6`, nothing` will be returned if `A={2,3,4}`, even though `{2,4}=6`. Also, your algorithm is O(n), so nothing more efficient can be written -- but something more correct can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the numbers stored in the input array are only positive then I'd create another  array K of k+1  ArrayList elements. Where k is the number you need them to add up to.
Only two numbers less than k can add up to k (assuming we deal with positive ints} or in special case {0,k}.
Then I would iterate through all elements of input array and for each int m that is less or equal to k I'd take its index and add that index to the array of ArrayList K at index m.
Then I would iterate through first half of the array K and for each index i that has some ints stored in it I would find complementary index [k-i] and see if there are any values in it. If there are then those are your pairs.
And btw this is O(n).

```
public static void findElemtsThatSumTo( int data[], int k){
    List arrayK[]= new List[k+1];
    for(int i=0; i<arrayK.length; i++)
        arrayK[i]= new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        if(data[i]<=k)
            arrayK[data[i]].add(i);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<arrayK.length/2; i++){
        if(!arrayK[i].isEmpty() && !arrayK[k-i].isEmpty())
        {
            for(Object index: arrayK[i])
                for(Object otherIndex: arrayK[k-i])
                    System.out.println("Numbers at indeces ["+index.toString()+", "+otherIndex.toString()+"] add up to "+k+".");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution. On this array input `{6,4,5,1,4,2,0}` I am getting answer as `Numbers at indeces [6, 0] add up to 6.
Numbers at indeces [3, 2] add up to 6.
Numbers at indeces [5, 1] add up to 6.
Numbers at indeces [5, 4] add up to 6.` Is there something wrong?

Comment: these are ineces, not values. Your array indeces are zero based so item at index 5 is integer 2 and item at index 4 is integer 4 so 2+4 is 6. All seems okay. You could convert that println statement to print values instead of indeces but indeces are more useful (IMO) as you can have the same number at manyy different indeces.

Answer (score 0):

As with your other question, O(log *n*) is impossible, since you have to examine the entire array. But O(n) is more or less possible.

If your range of possible integers is relatively small — that is, if it's within a constant factor of *n* — then you can write:

```
final boolean[] seen = new boolean[max - min + 1];
for(final int a : A)
{
    if(seen[input - a - min])
        System.out.println("{" + (input - a) + "," + a + "}");
    seen[a - min] = true;
}
```

If not, you can do the same thing, but using a `HashSet<Integer>` instead of an array:

```
final Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<Integer>();
for(final int a : A)
{
    if(seen.contains(input - a))
        System.out.println("{" + (input - a) + "," + a + "}");
    seen.add(a);
}
```

but that will not have *guaranteed* O(n) time.

Comment: Can you explain what's the problem with HashSet method as you said it's not guaranteed O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int arr[]={4,2,6,8,9,3,1};
    int sum=10;
    int arr1[]=new int[sum];


    for(int x=0;x<arr.length;x++)
    {
        arr1[arr[x]]++;
    }

    for(int y=0;y<arr.length;y++)
    {
        if(arr1[sum-arr[y]]==1)
        {
            System.out.println(arr[y]+","+(sum-arr[y]));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you provide some explanation about how this answers the question, or is more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

My little answer about this problem for O(n) complexity with O(n) additional memory. This code snippet returns all unique indices pair of elements with sum K.

```
/**
 * Returns indices of all complementary pairs in given {@code arr} with factor {@code k}. Two elements {@code arr[i]} and {@code arr[j]} are
 * complementary if {@code arr[i] + arr[j] = k}.
 * Method returns set of pairs in format {@literal [i,j]}. Two pairs {@literal [i,j]} and {@literal [j,i]} are treated as same, and only one pair
 * is returned.
 * Method support negative numbers in the {@code arr}, as wel as negative {@code k}.
 * <p>
 * Complexity of this method is <t>O(n)</t>, requires <t>O(n)</t> additional memory.
 *
 * @param arr source array
 * @param k   factor number
 * @return not {@code null} set of all complementary pairs in format {@literal [i,j]}
 */
public static Set<String> getComplementaryPairs(int[] arr, int k) {
    if (arr == null || arr.length == 0)
        return Collections.emptySet();

    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> indices = new TreeMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (!indices.containsKey(arr[i]))
            indices.put(arr[i], new TreeSet<>());
        indices.get(arr[i]).add(i);
    }

    Set<String> res = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Set<Integer>> entry : indices.entrySet()) {
        int x = entry.getKey();
        int y = k - x;

        if (x == y) {
            int size = entry.getValue().size();

            if (size < 2)
                continue;

            Integer[] ind = entry.getValue().toArray(new Integer[size]);

            for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++)
                for (int m = j + 1; m < size; m++)
                    res.add(String.format("[%d,%d]", ind[j], ind[m]));
        } else if (x < y && indices.containsKey(y))
            for (int j : entry.getValue())
                for (int m : indices.get(y))
                    res.add(String.format("[%d,%d]", j, m));
    }

    return res;
}
```