# Sum of two integers in an array equals K

Tags: algorithm

I read [Find two elements in an array that sum to k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630363/find-two-elements-in-an-array-that-sum-to-k) and [How can I find two elements in an array that sum to k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373614/how-can-i-find-two-elements-in-an-array-that-sum-to-k) as they are related.

I know a O(n) solution but i see that a O(n logn) also exists :-

```
p=0,q=n-1;
while(p<q)
{
  if(a[p]+a[q]==k)
  {
      cout<<a[p]<<"\t"<<a[q];
      p++;
      q--;
   }
   else if(a[p]+a[q]>k)
      q--;
   else 
      p++;
}
```

This requires the array to be first sorted. But since the values of p and q are dependent on the elements in the array, how do we assert that the complexity of this algorithm is O(n Log n)?

Comment: O(n log n) time *includes* the sort.

Comment: According to me this algorithm is of O(n) complexity since at each iteration you are increasing or decreasing atleast one counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity of an efficient sorting algorithm is `O(n log n)`.

No matter in what way the `p` and `q` changes, the `while` cycle will iterate through all the elements in the array once, thus it's complexity is `O(n)`.

Adding the two together: `O(n log n) + O(n) = O(n log n + n) = O(n log n)`, because n is much smaller than `n log n`, when `n` is a big number.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `O(n)` solution, you don't need to concern yourself with an `O(n log n)` one since that's *worse,* unless the `O(n)` solution has some other problem like a massive space complexity like `O(n^(n^(n^n)))` :-)

In any case, the algorithm you have shown is also `O(n)` since you either increase the low index or decrease the high index on each iteration.

I suspect the `O(n log n)` you mention includes an initial sort of unsorted data first, since that's a typical time complexity for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

In python

```
arr = [1, 2, 4, 6, 10]
diff_hash = {}
expected_sum = 3
for i in arr:
    if diff_hash.has_key(i):
        print i, diff_hash[i]
    key = expected_sum - i
    diff_hash[key] = i
```

Algo:

```
Input: expected_sum

diff_hash = hashtable_datastructure
for(i=0, i<len(arr), i++)
{ 
   if(diff_hash(arr[i])) 
   { 
      return arr[i] , diff_hash(arr[i])
   } 
   key = expected_sum - arr[i] 
   diff_hash(key) = arr[i] 
 }
```