# approch for homework: Does an array A with two numbers X & Y exist so that X+Y=Z - Use Hashing and time complexity should be O(n)

Tags: algorithm, hash-function

My task is in the title.

I guess a good start could be to use a hash function that seperates all number >Z from all numbers smaller Z. That would take O(n) time. But afterwards I would need to sort all Elements

Comment: What is exactly the input and output? Is it given an array A of (?) numbers and an integer Z, is there two elements X and Y in A s.t. X+Y=Z ?

Comment: With my teacher I'm never 100% sure what he wants but I think there is an Array A given with numbers, int for example, and I'm supposed to write an algorithm which checks if there are any numbers X and Y s.t. X+Y=Z. Z is a random number. Can I sum two numbers in my array somehow s.t. I get Z.

Comment: Yes so basically Dr Phil answer works.

Answer (score 1):

**Given**
To paraphrase the question: given an array a with n numeric elements and a number Z find whether there are to elements a[x], a[y] such that a[x]+[y]=Z.

**Approach:**
To do it in O(n) you could add each element to the array to a hash-set. - O(n).

Then another loop to check if Z-a[i] exists in the set another O(n) 
total O(n).

You can even combine the insertion and the check and do a few optimizations but it will still be O(n)

Comment: If that's indeed the question, then it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Olf if it is a duplicate can you link to the other answer/question?

Comment: plenty : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720271/find-a-pair-of-elements-from-an-array-whose-sum-equals-a-given-number?rq=1https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630363/find-two-elements-in-an-array-that-sum-to-k https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815116/given-two-arrays-a-and-b-find-all-pairs-of-elements-a1-b1-such-that-a1-belong https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373614/how-can-i-find-two-elements-in-an-array-that-sum-to-k

Comment: Good. Another paraphrasing

Comment: I found a good solution I think. Thanks for your help :). 

But the links are not the same question I think. My task explicitly says "use Hashing".  Non of the links use Hashing.