# Fast Ruby method / algorithm to pair elements of two arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm, sorting, coupling

I have two *sorted* arrays of float numbers (usually 800-1500 elements), size of the two arrays can be different by +-20-30 %.
I am looking for a fast method which pick a correspondent pair of all elements of the smaller array from the elements of the biggest array on the basis of minimal difference.

Currently I am using this

```
def get_pairs(ary1,ary2)
  if ary1.size<ary2.size then
    smaller=ary1;bigger=ary2
  else
    smaller=ary2;bigger=ary1;
  end
  p=Array.new(smaller.size)
  smaller.each_with_index do |z,i|
     pair=bigger.min_by{|elem| (elem-z).abs}
     p[i]=[z, pair]
  end
  return p
end
```

This is the key element of my program, it is called very often and unfortunately it is too slow for me.

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815116/given-two-arrays-a-and-b-find-all-pairs-of-elements-a1-b1-such-that-a1-belong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using `min_by` is that you have to iterate over every single element of `bigger` for each element of `smaller`. Try breaking early once you've found the pair with lowest difference.

```
def get_pairs(a, b)
  smaller, bigger = [a, b].map(&:sort).sort_by(&:length)

  smaller.map do |x|
    lowest_diff = nil
    lowest_element = nil

    bigger.each_with_index do |y, i|
      diff = (x - y).abs

      if lowest_diff.nil? || diff < lowest_diff
        lowest_diff = diff
        lowest_element = y
      elsif diff > lowest_diff || y == bigger.last
        break [x, lowest_element]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thx, I don't understand exactly but it works and reasonably faster!

Comment: @Konstantin Think of it this way - with your original algorithm, if the small array had 1,000 elements and the big array had 1,000 elements, you would need to execute 1,000,000 comparisons! The algorithm that I posted exits the loop once it finds the 'optimal' pair, so requires far fewer comparisons.

Comment: Sometimes it fails, I am using this version now:
`
def get_p2_fast(a,b)
  if a.size<=b.size then
    smaller=a;bigger=b
  else
    smaller=b;nagyobb=a;
  end
  p=Array.new(smaller.size)
  pointer=0
  smaller.each_with_index do |z,i|
     while z-bigger[pointer]>=0 && pointer<=bigger.size-2 do
       pointer=pointer+1
     end
     if (bigger[pointer]-z).abs<=(bigger[pointer-1]-z).abs then
       pair=bigger[pointer]
     else
       pair=bigger[pointer-1]
       pointer=pointer-1
     end
     p[i]=[z, pair]
  end
  return p
end
`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it fails, I am using this version now:

```
def get_p2_fast(a,b)
  if a.size<=b.size then
    smaller=a;bigger=b
  else
    smaller=b;nagyobb=a;
  end
  p=Array.new(smaller.size)
  pointer=0
  smaller.each_with_index do |z,i|
     while z-bigger[pointer]>=0 && pointer<=bigger.size-2 do
       pointer=pointer+1
     end
     if (bigger[pointer]-z).abs<=(bigger[pointer-1]-z).abs then
       pair=bigger[pointer]
     else
       pair=bigger[pointer-1]
       pointer=pointer-1
     end
     p[i]=[z, pair]
  end
  return p
end
```