# Find pair from 2 list whose sum is equal to given value

Tags: python-2.7, performance, for-loop, execution-time

We have two integer arrays, a and b, and an integer target value v. Determine whether there is a pair of numbers, where one number is taken from a and the other from b, that can be added together to get a sum of v. Return true if such a pair exists, otherwise return false.

For example:
For `a = [1, 2, 3]`, `b = [10, 20, 30, 40]`, and `v = 42`, the output should be

```
sumOfTwo(a, b, v) = True
```

My code so far:

```
def sumOfTwo(a, b, v):
    for x in a:
        for y  in b:
            if x+y == v:
                return True
    return False
```

I want to reduce the execution time, as its taking long to execute long lists.

Comment: Are the given two lists sorted?? If so, it's pretty simple then.

Comment: No, tried with sorted also, but unable to reduce the execution time. Also tried `res = any(v-x in b for x in a)`

Comment: Roughly how long are these "long lists"?

Comment: 10,000 items or even more.

Comment: Related / possible dup: [The fastest way to find 2 numbers from two lists that in sum equal to x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33591516/the-fastest-way-to-find-2-numbers-from-two-lists-that-in-sum-equal-to-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be much faster if you first convert `b` to a set:

```
def sumOfTwo(a, b, v):
    b = set(b)
    return any(v - x in b for x in a)
```

The complexity should be O(M + N) in stead of O(MN) for the brute force solution.