# Algorithm of O(nlogn) to search for sum of two elements in two arrays

Tags: algorithm

Given two *sorted* arrays of integers A1, A2, with the same length `n` and an integer `x`, I need to write an algorithm that runs in O(nlog(n)) that determines whether there exist two elements `a1, a2` (one element in each array) that make `a1+a2=x`.

At first I thought about having two index iterators `i1=0, i2=0` (one for each array) that start from 0 and increase one at a time, depending on the next element of A1 being bigger/smaller than the next element of A2. But after testing it on two arrays I found out that it might miss some possible solutions...

Comment: In my opinion, iterating through every element `a` of `A1` and binary searching for `x - a` in `A2` should do the trick.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given two arrays a and b .Find all pairs of elements (a1,b1) such that a1 belongs to Array A and b1 belongs to Array B whose sum a1+b1 = k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815116/given-two-arrays-a-and-b-find-all-pairs-of-elements-a1-b1-such-that-a1-belong)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, as they are both sorted already, the algorithm should be O(n) (sorting would be O(n * log(n))):

```
i1 = 0
i2 = A2.size - 1
while i1 < A1.size and i2 >= 0
    if A1[i1] + A2[i2] < x
        ++i1
    else if A1[i1] + A2[i2] > x
        --i2
    else
        success!!!!
```

Comment: How did you come up with this? Im having trouble in university with coming with these on my own

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange question because there is an inelegant solution in time `O(N Lg N)` (for every element of A1, lookup A2 for `x-a1` by dichotomic search), and a nice one requiring only `O(N)` operations.

Start from the left of A1 and the right of A2 and move left in A2 as long as `a1+a2≥x`. Then move right one position in A1 and update in A2 if needed...

Answer (score 1):

You start one array from index = 0 = i and the other in reverse other = j.
First step you know you have the smallest in the list A and the biggest in the list B so you subtract i from x, then move the j index down until the value =< X

Basically you have 2 indexes moving towards the middle 
If value of index i > value of index j then there is no such sum that match x.